# SDL2 Window not rendering

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2

OS: MacOS 12.0.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Will You Ball?", 0, 0, 700, 700, 0);

    if(window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "FAILED TO OPEN WINDOW";
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    // Draw Square
    SDL_Rect rect = { 0, 0, 70, 70 };
    SDL_FillRect(screen, &rect, SDL_MapRGB(screen -> format, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));

    SDL_Delay(10000);

    return 0;
}
```

The app runs and compiles without any errors however the window never opens. Is this a problem with MacOS or my code?

Comment: Did it print "FAILED TO OPEN WINDOW"

Comment: Add an event loop. You'll need it anyway, it should be explained in the tutorial you're using. Some OSes refuse to render a window without one.

Comment: @drescherjm it did not print FAILED TO OPEN WINDOW

Comment: After you get that event looping going, where's your [`SDL_UpdateWindowSurface()`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.0.20/include/SDL_video.h#L1239-L1256) call?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That seems to have been the problem. Was just reading the documentation for creating a new window on the sdl wiki or whatever its called. Found an actual tutorial that explains stuff now (: